# Proving that $\det(A) \ne 0$ if $a_{i,i} = 0$ and $a_{i,j} = \pm 1$ for $i \neq j$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix ($n=2k$, $k \in \Bbb N^*$) such that.
>
> $$a_{ij} =
> \begin{cases}
> \pm 1,  & \text{if $i \ne j$} \\
> 0, & \text{if $i=j$}
> \end{cases}$$
>
> Show that $\det (A) \ne 0$.

P.S. $a_{ij}=\pm 1$ means that it can be $+1$ or $-1$ not necessarily the same for all $a_{ij}$.

**My approach:**

I've started with the definition of $\det A$ writing like a permutation sum but it became messy. I also tried Laplace's method but also didn't work. I also tried induction but once $\pm 1$ is aleatory it became tough to deal with.

Comment: Have you tried with the cofactor expansion by induction?

Comment: @Euler: Yeap! When I used induction combined with Laplace!

Comment: @ArnaldoNascimento Maybe you could post your solution as Answer (I'd be interested to read it)

Comment: @ArnaldoNascimento , yeah posting it would be useful. When doing induction it might work, by splitting it into cases depending if $n$ is even or odd, it should work

Comment: but yeah it would become very messy..maybe strong induction would do better

Comment: Using induction I don't know how to move in it because the minors doesn't have the same form as $A$. I'm trying to think out of the box now.

Comment: If you can prove that by replacing one of the zeros in the main diagonal by $\pm 1$, the determinant remains different from zero, then you are done. Because when you are doing the inductive step, that's all you need!

Comment: @Alex: How easy is that? Do you have a solution?

Comment: when you expand using cofactors, use for example the first row. Then the first minor is multiplied by zero, all the others are like the $n\times n$ matrix (that has determinant different from zero by assumption) with one zero replaced by $\pm 1$

Comment: this fact is easy to prove as all the rows will be linearly independent I think..not sure tbh

Comment: @Alex: Please, post a proof of that!

Comment: @Pierre: They can be different. That is the big problem.

Comment: Ok! It is not the same for all $a_{ij}$!

Comment: So sorry guys! $n$ must to be a even number! My bad!

Comment: So in the end, there was a solution by cofactor expansion.

Comment: I think a particular case of this matrix is a skew symmetric matrix, where if $n$ is even, then determinant is always non-negative and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assume that $n$ is even. Consider your matrix $A$ as being a matrix with integer coefficient, and let $\mathbb{F}_2$ be the field with two elements.  Then the projection $\pi:\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{F}_2$ induces a projection $\pi$ on the rings of matrices; let $A_2$ be the image of $A$ by this projection.  Then $\det(A_2) = \pi(\det(A))$.

Now, let $B$ be the matrix defined in the same way as $A$, except that all non-zero entries are $1$ (instead of $\pm 1$).  Then $\pi(B)= A_2$.  Now $B$ is a [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix), and we know that its determinant is $(n-1)\cdot(-1)^n$.  Hence $\det(A_2)=1$, so $\det(A)$ cannot be zero (in fact, it cannot be an even number).

Note that this also shows that if $n$ is odd, then $\det(A)$ will always be an even number.

---

**Added:**

After seeing Omnomnomnom's answer, I realized that the matrix $A_2$ above is invertible, and is its own inverse, if $n$ is even.  So there's no need to use the circulant matrix $B$ in the proof.

---

**And if $n$ is odd:**

The result is false if $n$ is odd.  A counter-example for $n=3$ is given by the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

If $n$ is any odd integer, then this counter-example generalizes: let $A$ have $1$'s everywhere, except on the diagonal, and also on the last row, where $1$ and $-1$ alternate.  Then $A$ has zero determinant, since the vector $(1,1,\ldots,1,n-2)^t$ is in its kernel.

Comment: Thank you @Pierre, nice, +1. Your matrix $B$ gave me an idea for another proof, I wrote down it.

Comment: CAUTION: You can not deduce that if it is not true for $n = 3$ it is also not true for all odd $n$. This requires a proof.

Comment: I understand, however I think the question has been edited asking just for $n$ even after your CORRECT answer  which I do not refute. I wanted only to say that it remains the possibility of the statement be true for (at least some maybe)  odd $n\ne3$.

Comment: @Piquito There, I've added a counter-example for all odd $n$ :)

Comment: Very good. This completes your proof.

Answer (score 8):

**Without finite fields:** We wish to show that $\det(A)$ is necessarily odd (which we concluded from the $\Bbb F_2$ approach), which would imply $\det(A) \neq 0$.  Fix a matrix $A$ of the described pattern.
Let $A^{(i,j)}$ denote the matrix in which we "flip" the sign of the $i,j$ entry.  That is,
$$
A^{(i,j)}_{pq} = \begin{cases}
-A_{ij} & p=i,q=j\\
A_{ij} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
By applying the Laplace expansion of the determinant along the $i$th row, we see
$$
\det(A) - \det(A^{(i,j)}) = 2C_{ij}
$$
Where $C_{ij}$ is the [cofactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) associated with $i,j$.  Notably, $C_{ij}$ is an integer.

So, flipping one sign won't change the parity of the derivative.  Thus, is sufficient to show that the matrix $A$ whose off-diagonal entries are all $1$ has an odd determinant.  But this is easy.

In particular, if $x$ is the column vector whose entries are all $1$, then we want to show that $\det(xx^T - I)$ is odd.  We can do so either by considering the eigenvalues of the rank-$1$ matrix $xx^T$ or by [Sylvester's determinant identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_determinant_identity) (or by row-reduction, or by observing that the matrix is circulant).  Whichever way you choose, we find $\det(xx^T - I) = 1-n$, which is necessarily odd.

---

Another slick proof using finite fields (which avoids appealing to circulant matrices):

Consider the $n \times n$ matrix $B$ whose entries (from $\Bbb F_2$) are all $1$.  Since $n$ is even, we find that $B^2 = nB = 0$. Since $B$ is nilpotent, its only eigenvalue is $0$ (with multiplicity $n$).

The matrix $A$ (taken modulo $2$) is given by $A = B + I$.  Since $B$ has eigenvalue $0$ with multiplicity $n$, we may conclude that $A$ has eigenvalue $1$ with multiplicity $n$. Thus, $\det(A) = (1)^n = 1 \neq 0$.

Thus, we conclude that the determinant of an $A$ of the presented form is odd, hence non-zero.

---

Or, more simply: $B^2 = 0$.  So, $A = B+I$ is invertible since 
$$
A^2 = B^2 + 2B + I = 0 + 0 +I = I
$$

Comment: Come to think of it, $A^2=(B+I)^2 = I$ modulo $2$, so $A$ is invertible...

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon well spotted!

Answer (score 8):

Thank you @Pierre-Guy, your solution and particularly the matrix $B$ gave me an idea.

If we write $\det A$ using congruence modulo $2$, we get that $\pm 1$ will became $1$ and then we have:

$$\det A \equiv\begin{vmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 1 & ...&1 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 & ...&1 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & ...&1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 & ...&0
\end{vmatrix}$$

and sum every horizontal line at the first we have:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
        2k-1 & 2k-1 & 2k-1 & ...&2k-1 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 & ...&1 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & ...&1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 & ...&0
\end{vmatrix}=(2k-1)\begin{vmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 & ...&1 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 & ...&1 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & ...&1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 & ...&0
\end{vmatrix}$$

Now if we subtract every horizontal line from the first line we get:

$$(2k-1)\begin{vmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 & ...&1 \\
        0 & -1 & 1 & ...&1 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & ...&1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & ...&-1
\end{vmatrix}=(2k-1)(-1)^{(2k-1)}\equiv 1 \mod 2$$

and so the $\det A$ is a odd number and then it can't be $0$.

Comment: You could also compute this determinant by noting that $\det A = \det (\mathbf 1 \mathbf 1^T - I)$ and using the [matrix-determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) where $\mathbf 1$ is the vector of all $1$s.

Comment: @Chaconne: nice hint! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Here's an approach which connects to your original idea of writing out the definition of $\det A$ as a sum over permutations:

If you to this, you get $n!$ terms, each of which is either $+1$, $-1$ or $0$. The terms which are zero are the ones where you include at least one matrix entry from the diagonal, so they correspond exactly to the permutations $\pi$ which have at least one fixpoint (i.e., $\pi(k)=k$ for some $k$).

So the **nonzero** terms in the sum correspond to the **fixpoint-free** permutations, also known as [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement). And the number of derangements of $n$ elements, call it $a_n$, is **odd** if $n$ is even (and even if $n$ is odd), which is easy to prove from the recursion
$$
a_1=0
,\qquad
a_n = n a_{n-1} + (-1)^n
.
$$
So your determinant is the sum of an **odd** number of $+1$ and $-1$, hence it is itself an odd number, and can't be zero.

Comment: Nice,+1. Good idea.