# Rank of matrix with diagonal 0, and others +-1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank

Let $B$ be a $(n-1)×(n-1)$ matrix such that: all elements on diagonal equal $0$; and all other either $1$ or $\text{-}1$.

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}B&(1,...,1)^T\\
(1,...,1)&1\end{bmatrix}$, so $A$ be a $n×n$ derived from $B$ by adding a row and column with $1$.

What could be the rank of the matrix $A$ ?

Comment: As established [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2065868/81360), $B$ has a submatrix of rank at most $n-2$.  Since this submatrix is in turn a submatrix of $A$, it follows that the rank of $A$ is $n-2$, $n-1$, or $n$.

I suspect, however, that $A$ will generally be invertible (with odd determinant).

Comment: If we replace the bottom-right entry with a $0$, we get a matrix that, when taken modulo $2$, has eigenvalues $n-1$ with multiplicity $1$ and $-1$ with multiplicity $n-1$.  I have not found a way to leverage this fact.

Answer (score 2):

$A$ is necessarily of full rank, since its determinant is non-zero.  We can show that the determinant is non-zero by showing that it is necessarily an odd number.

Following [Hans's idea here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2066079/81360), showing that $A$ always has odd determinant is equivalent to showing that the number of permutations on $n$ objects that either have no fixed point **or** fix only the final entry is odd.  If $d_n$ denotes the number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement), then we wish to show that $d_n + d_{n-1}$ is necessarily odd.

We note that $d_n$ satisfies the recurrence relation 
$$
d_1 = 0, \quad d_n = n d_{n-1} + (-1)^n
$$
so that $d_n$ is odd iff $d_{n-1}$ is even.  It follows that $d_n + d_{n-1}$ is always the sum of an even and odd number, and is therefore odd.

Comment: $d_{n-1}$ corresponds to permutations with fixed one element, bottom right entry.     And     $d_{n}$ corresponds to permutations without fixed elements  ?

Comment: Exactly ${}{}{}{}{}$